# How to grep an empty string?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I would like to grep for "String = " and when nothing is mentioned...when it's empty...echo with an if then else statement:

I tried something like that:

```
if grep "String" input.txt | sed -e 's/    String = //g' | egrep -q "^$"
then
<command> > output.txt
else
echo "--" > output.txt
fi
```

When I use the sed command the line is empty.

Thx in advance!

**UPDATE**
these are some possible lines in input.txt

```
String = TextA
String = 
String = TextB
```

Comment: Could you accept any of the answers or say why they don't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this `grep` to check for `String =` in the input file:

```
if grep -Eq 'String *= *$' input.txt; then
    <command> > output.txt
else
   echo "--" > output.txt
fi
```

Comment: Doens't work...there are no spaces after 'String = '

Comment: First you wrote: **My string has two spaces: "String = '** now saying: **.there are no spaces after 'String = '** However this grep command works whether there are 0 or more spaces around `=`.

Comment: I mean on space before "=" and one after. Please see my update.

Comment: Spaces around = are fine and they will be matched by the regex in my answer.

Comment: Also test grip output by running `grep -E 'String *= *$' input.txt` command on command line.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using awk:

```
CMD=$(awk '$1=="String" {print $3}' input.txt)
if [ -n "$CMD" ]
then
    CMD="--"
fi
echo "$CMD" > output.txt
```

some explanations:

- awk prints the third column (since there is a space before and after the `=` sign; that is the 2nd column)
- the line `if [ -n "$CMD" ]` just tests if the variable `CMD` is empty

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you are having trouble finding the specified lines in the file. The following grep command will find those lines:

```
egrep 'String[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*' input.txt
```

Adapt it to your if/else statements and it should work.

Or, if you want to specify that there is one space before the "=", do:

```
egrep 'String[[:space:]]{1}=[[:space:]]*;
```